# JSDoc with typescript, defining custom object key type doesn't raise error

Tags: typescript, jsdoc

Adding anything other than generic types doesn't type check on key-map objects

Example:

```
/**
 * @typedef {"MARKET1"|"MARKET2"|"MARKET3"} Market
 * @typedef {{
    name: string,
   }} Item

  this type checks just items, not keys
 * @typedef {{
    items: Object.<string, Item[]>,
   }} Config
   
  this doesn't type check anything, even items
  having a non generic type in the key field doesn't raise any error
 * @typedef {{
    items: Object.<Market, Item[]>
   }} Config  
*/
```

Comment: Why are you using JSDoc typedefs with typescript

Comment: it is a small project so no need for project-wise typescript. i am only using JSDoc for validating a config file. typescript looks a bit overkill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the utility type [`Record`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type) instead of `Object.<key, value>`. It's going to be like the snippet below:

```js
/**
 * @typedef {"MARKET1"|"MARKET2"|"MARKET3"} Market
 * @typedef {{
    name: string,
   }} Item
 */

/**
 * @typedef {{
  items: Record<string, Item[]>,
 }} Config1
 */

/**
 * @typedef {{
  items: Record<Market, Item[]>
 }} Config2
 */
```

[image]

[image]